# Point 2nd domain name to existing site whilst retaining email accounts

Tags: email, dns, cpanel, domain-name, nameservers

I tried searching on SO but all answers seem to involve .htaccess and 301 redirects. I am wondering if there is a way to do this just using cpanel and the DNS providers interface.

Simply I own two domain names: `mysite.com` and `thissite.com`

Both are currently pointing to servers and both have email addresses associated with them.

I want to point `thissite.com` to `mysite.com` without disrupting the email addresses already associated with `thissite.com`

At first I changed the nameservers of `thissite.com` to be the same as `mysite.com` but this disrupted the emails so I quickly changed them back.

I then changed the A record of `thissite.com` to point to the IP address of `mysite.com`. The same issue seems to have occurred though - the email addresses are still broken.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Thanks

Comment: This question fits better for superuser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally A records are not related to emails. Possibly your email problems caused by DNS still cached since your first experiment.

DNS stores a destination SMTP **server** where email for the domain in an MX-type record. See what MX record you have for thissite.com.

```
nslookup
set type=mx
thissite.com
```

If your domain have correct MX records, then the A record do not matter for emails.

Comment: Yes you are right. Adjusting the A records worked. I just had to wait for propagation back to the original name-servers